# spring-test and mockito controller test

Tags: java, mockito, spring-test

```
@Test
public void testWelcomePage() throws Exception {
    UserDto dto = new UserDto("admin");
    UserEntity user = new UserEntity("admin");
    when(userServiceMock.getUser(dto)).thenReturn(user);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/main/user/welcome?loginId=admin"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("user/welcome"))
        .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/pages/user/welcome.jsp")) 
        .andExpect(model().attribute("user", hasProperty("loginId", is("admin")))); //-->java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'user' .... but: was null...

    verify(userServiceMock, times(1)).getUser(dto); //-->Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(userServiceMock);
}
```

UserDto is object passed by spring mvc form object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(UserDto userDto, ModelMap model, Locale locale) {
    UserEntity user = null;
    try {
        user = userService.getUser(userDto);
    } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        model.addAttribute("message", messageSource.getMessage("msg.data.notfound", null, locale));
    }
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "user/welcome";
}
```

But, mockito throws assertion error at passed argument(UserDto id different).
How can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you don't need the verification, isn't it enough that the `user` is in the model?

Comment: I guess, the UserDto object you are expecting in your mock statement when(userServiceMock.getUser(dto)).thenReturn(user); is not same as the UserDto object in actual statement userService.getUser(userDto); That is why it's not really mocking the actual statement while execution, hence it is returning null. The object being passed to the actual statement while execution must be same as the object at the time of expecting, then only it will return the object you expected

Answer (score 0):

UserDto object needs to override equals() method.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
}
```

completed!